# What might cause overestimated measured pH value of sodium hydroxide solution pumped with carbon dioxide?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, experimental-chemistry, aqueous-solution, ph

I tried an experiment at home where I had a $\ce{CO2}$ tank pumping $\ce{CO2}$ into a solution of $\pu{28 g}$ sodium hydroxide in $\pu{200 ml}$ water. The initial $\mathrm{pH}$ was $11.24.$

I expected it to form sodium carbonate and bicarbonate, but instead, the $\mathrm{pH}$ went up to $11.5.$ I should point out that my $\mathrm{pH}$ sensor needed a few minutes of cleaning in distilled water to prevent inaccuracy because the sodium hydroxide particles stuck to it.

Is this supposed to happen, or is my $\mathrm{pH}$ sensor inaccurate? Is there another way to do it? I also found some videos online and in those videos, the $\mathrm{pH}$ went acidic instead of the $\mathrm{pH}$ of sodium carbonate which is between $8$ and $10.$

Comment: The initial pH should be >14, and after adding CO2, it should drop. NaOH is very soluble in water, so it is strange that you talk of sodium hydroxide particles.

Answer (score 1):

pH measurements at extreme pHs are not accurate. It is not a surprise that you find unpredicted changes in pH after bubbling carbon dioxide because the sensor is not meant for such a high concentration of NaOH. There are well known sodium errors associated with glass electrodes. The sensor is not faulty, it is not designed to be used in concentrated alkalies! The electrode starts to respond to Na ions instead.

If you are talking of "particles", sodium carbonate can precipitate in strong caustic solutions, so you can indeed see particulates of sodium carbonate depending on the concentration.

Comment: Thanks for your help but do you recommend I use a better pH sensor or would that not work as well?

Comment: No pH sensor will work at such a high concentration. What are you trying to do? What is your experiment about?

Comment: I am trying to add co2 to sodium hydroxide to form sodium carbonate for a science experiment. If a pH meter can't measure that high, should I just make carbonic acid, use the pH sensor,  and then add sodium hydroxide and not measure it?

Comment: You cannot make carbonic acid. It does not exist. If you explain more what you are trying to demonstrate in your experiment, one can think of a solution. Is this a student project or you are teaching ?

Comment: Just for a student projet, I am trying to demonstrate the ansrobsion of co2 through a sodium hydroxide solution and turning it into sodium carbonate. A few months back I did the same thing with water instead and the ph dropped from 7.4 to 4.7 in the co2/water experiment. But I don't understand what you mean when you said carbonic acid doesn't exist.

Comment: Instead of pH sensor use a universal indicator to show the changes in pH and use dilute 0.01 M NaOH. Why did you choose such a high conc. to begin with?

Comment: I added a high concentration because I thought the pH of the sodium hydroxide solution should be between 12-14

Comment: Your concentration of NaOH is way more than 1 M.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I have one more question, will adding co2 to a sodium hydroxide solution have the same effect as adding sodium hydroxide POWDER to carbonic acid?

Comment: There is no carbonic acid. If you are interesting in doing a demo, I told you the universal indicator way with a dilute NaOH solution (< 1 M) to show how CO2 is decreasing the pH of the caustic solution.

Comment: Would pH strips also work?

Comment: Yes, they should.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I redid it with ph strips and the ph went from 14 to 11!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you start with a pH of 11.24 and it jumps to 11.5, that would be more basic, not more acidic. Using some pH calculators, the pH of your initial NaOH solution should have been 14.54, NaOH being very basic. After pumping excess CO<sub>2</sub> through it, the pH of your Na<sub>2</sub>CO<sub>3</sub> solution should have turned out to be 10.25. For this situation, I would say you either have a faulty pH sensor, or there is some other source of error that would change the results so drastically. Most likely the former.

This is completely up to you, but if you are planning on getting a new pH sensor, I recommend Sensorex. They have a few options, including one for about \$50, or a more sensitive one for around $100.
https://sensorex.com/laboratory-ph-electrodes/?hsCtaTracking=6c3ce343-9554-4fba-8b74-8d232f941f6f%7Cf9b4d806-dea3-4aff-a8e9-7df730ead108